# The meaning of "hello"

Tags: meaning

*Goodnight Mommy: hello chilly Austrian matricide horror*

Source: http://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/aug/31/goodbye-mommy-hello-chilly-austrian-matricide-horror-venice-review

This is the title of the movie review. Could you explain to me the meaning of the word "hello" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hello" here means the same thing as it usually does: a greeting.

"Hello chilly Austrian matricide horror" is meant to summarize the movie: viewers will encounter "chilly Austrian matricide horror", so the sentence suggests that they will "greet" it.  This is a fairly common idiom.  Besides being used to literally greet people, *hello* can be used to call attention to something else that one is encountering, as in the opening line from the Simon and Garfunkel song "The Sound of Silence": *Hello darkness, my old friend*.

This is also meant to mimic the film's title *Goodnight Mommy*.  The phrase *good night* is commonly said when saying goodbye to someone (at night), so this is placed in contrast to the greeting *hello*.

Also, a sentence of the form *goodbye X, hello Y* is sometimes used to mean "X is ending and Y is beginning".  So this headline plays on that form as well.